# Fluent validation not work on kendo dropdown

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

hi  i am using a Kendo drop down control and i used Fluent validation in it but when i run it . validation not work on kendo drop down.

This Is Kendo drop down which bind by Parent_Category_ID

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model=>model.Parent_Category_ID)
          .Name("Parent_Category_ID")
          .OptionLabel("-----------Select Parent Category-----------")
          .DataTextField("CategoryName")
          .DataValueField("ID")
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:300px", })
          .Filter(FilterType.StartsWith)
          .DataSource(source =>
          {
              source.Read(read =>
              {
                  read.Action("GetCategory", "Category");
              })
              .ServerFiltering(true);
          })
    )
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Parent_Category_ID)
```

and That is my fluent Control ModelValidator

```
public CategoryValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.Category_Name).NotNull().WithMessage("Category Must Not be Empty !").Length(6).WithMessage("Category Name should be 6 character Long !");
            RuleFor(x => x.Parent_Category_ID).NotNull().WithMessage("Parent Category must Not be empty !");
            RuleFor(x => x.Category_Desc).NotNull().WithMessage("Please Write Some Description !");
        }
```

and This Category Models

```
 public class CategoryModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int Category_ID { get; set; }
        public int Parent_Category_ID { get; set; }
        public string Category_Name { get; set; }
        public string Category_Desc { get; set; }
        public bool IsGenderApplicable { get; set; }
        public bool IsAgeApplicable { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your CategorValidator, you have a duplicate rule for Parent_Category_ID. Based on the validation message, looks like it is not intentional.

Comment: its typing mistake .... but when if i use validation on it... validation not work..